# Genymotion emulator display not render correctly

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen, genymotion

I have installed and start Genymotion emulator in my Windows 10 x64 PC. But emulator screen not render mostly text correctly.

- Genymotion version - 3.1.2
- Virtualbox version - 6.0.4 r128413 (Qt5.6.2)

Following is the settings screen.

[image: Setting screen]

Answer (score 0):

Fount out that problem exist with the newer versions of Genymotion. So I downgraded to version 2.12.1 . Now no problem. Don't know why.